# Why some believe that Apocalypse will be triggered by The Temple of Solomon?

Tags: eschatology, revelation, israel, temple, john-apostle

Maybe this question is better suited for Biblical Hermeneutics, but it is on-topic here too.

We know that King Solomon built a temple in Jerusalem for God, then the Assyrians or Babylonians (I forget which) destroyed the temple and scattered the Israelites to foreign lands. Eventually they were sent home by the King of Persia and they rebuilt the temple.

Then the Romans came and destroyed the temple shortly after Jesus's life and Resurrection and the Jews were once again scattered to foreign lands. In the 20th century after WW2 the Israelites had an initiative to return to "The Promised Land" — many of them have, where they have been in regular conflict with the Arabs.

My question is why do some Christians believe that when the Jews will rebuild the Temple of Solomon for the third time, and that this will trigger the Apocalypse and the Second Coming of Christ. Does this have a biblical basis. Is this mentioned in the apostle John's Revelation?

Comment: Please show the source of your claim that some Christians believe a rebuilt Temple in Jerusalm will trigger the Apocalypse and the Second Coming of Christ.  As it stands, your question requires clarification (showing the sources of your own research) and will likely attract opinion-based answers. You also need to specify which religious groups or denominations you seek answers from.

Answer (score 3):

@Lesley is correct that there are specific details concerning this issue that are unique to individual Christian traditions. However, I believe I can answer your question on a basic level.

What you're talking about is the *Abomination of Desolation* first described by the ancient prophet Daniel.

> And arms shall stand on his part, and they shall pollute the sanctuary of strength, and shall take away the daily sacrifice, and they shall place the abomination that maketh desolate. (Daniel 11:31, KJV)

> And from the time that the daily sacrifice shall be taken away, and the abomination that maketh desolate set up, there shall be a thousand two hundred and ninety days. (Daniel 12:11, KJV)

Confusion occurs because Jesus later describes an *Abomination of Desolation,* but the description appears to be in terms of the last days before His second coming.

> But take heed to yourselves: for they shall deliver you up to councils; and in the synagogues ye shall be beaten: and ye shall be brought before rulers and kings for my sake, for a testimony against them. And the gospel must first be published among all nations. But when they shall lead you, and deliver you up, take no thought beforehand what ye shall speak, neither do ye premeditate: but whatsoever shall be given you in that hour, that speak ye: for it is not ye that speak, but the Holy Ghost.
>
> Now the brother shall betray the brother to death, and the father the son; and children shall rise up against their parents, and shall cause them to be put to death. And ye shall be hated of all men for my name’s sake: but he that shall endure unto the end, the same shall be saved.
>
> But when ye shall see the abomination of desolation, spoken of by Daniel the prophet, standing where it ought not, (let him that readeth understand,) then let them that be in Judæa flee to the mountains: (Mark 13:9-14, KJV)

This description suggests that the *Abomination of Desolation* (a forceful cessation of the daily sacrifice, possibly the destruction of the Temple) will occur after the Apostles of Christ's time would be martyred, after the gospel had been preached to all nations, and after wickedness had progressed to a point that "children shall rise up against their parents, and shall cause them to be put to death."

The Romans destroyed the Jewish Temple in 70 A.D. It is believed that the Apostle John died after that date. By the time of John's death, the gospel had been taught to many areas around the Mediterranean Sea and a few areas beyond, but that might (and might not...) not be enough to fulfill the prophesy about the gospel going to all the world. Therefore, it is believed that the Roman destruction of the Temple was not the *Abomination of Desolation* Jesus was talking about in the books of Matthew and Mark.

If we accept that the above description describes the destruction of a Jewish Temple in the last days (some day future of today since one hasn't been built since the Roman destruction), then we learn from the Book of Matthew that the *Abomination of Desolation* will occur soon before a series of signs portending the coming end of the world.

> And as he sat upon the mount of Olives, the disciples came unto him privately, saying, Tell us, when shall these things be? and what shall be the sign of thy coming, and of the end of the world? ... When ye therefore shall see the abomination of desolation, spoken of by Daniel the prophet, stand in the holy place, (whoso readeth, let him understand:) ... Immediately after the tribulation of those days shall the sun be darkened, and the moon shall not give her light, and the stars shall fall from heaven, and the powers of the heavens shall be shaken: and then shall appear the sign of the Son of man in heaven: and then shall all the tribes of the earth mourn, and they shall see the Son of man coming in the clouds of heaven with power and great glory. (Matthew 24:3, 15, 29-30, KJV)

The signs Jesus described appear to be those at the opening of the Six Seal in John's Revelation (sun darkened, stars fall from heaven):

> And I beheld when he had opened the sixth seal, and, lo, there was a great earthquake; and the sun became black as sackcloth of hair, and the moon became as blood; and the stars of heaven fell unto the earth, even as a fig tree casteth her untimely figs, when she is shaken of a mighty wind. (Revelation 6:12-13, KJV)

Followed by the second coming, itself. There are many differences between Christian traditions concerning what Jesus meant by "the sign of the Son of man in heaven: and then shall all the tribes of the earth mourn, and they shall see the Son of man coming in the clouds of heaven with power and great glory," but at least one that I'm familiar with suggests this summarizes the opening of the Seventh Seal in John's Revelation (Revelation chapters 8-10).

**Conclusion**

I do not believe it's correct to say that the destruction or desecration of a modern Jewish Temple would "trigger the apocalypse." I believe it's better to say that this modern *Abomination of Desolation* is one of the signs of the coming of our Lord — and that its placement in the order of things appears to be at the end of the period of the Fifth Seal.

However, @Lesley is correct that even that summary statement will be debated by different Christian traditions. There's uncertainty concerning prophesies of the future. But my hope is that I've provided the basic Biblical foundation for the belief in a latter-day *Abomination of Desecration* and, because it's prophesied to occur (apparently) before the opening of the Sixth Seal, is precedes the Apocalypse.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't say that some say that destruction of the New Temple will trigger the end of the world, but the building of it, because currently the Temple wasn't rebuilt since its destruction 2000 years ago.

Comment: @Bogdan That's the same thing, you're just pointing to the beginning of the story (the construction of the Temple) rather than the end (the destruction of the Temple). Please note that I don't know of any Christian tradition that focuses on the construction of the temple other than the assumption that it must happen (otherwise, there's nothing to destroy later). The destruction/desecration of the Temple is the only Biblical reference I'm aware of.

Comment: You are right. Some people believe that Paul also told Corinthians about the profanity of the temple, even if the Temple was destroyed at the time of Paul ministry

Comment: I think the correct interpretation of this would be that the profanity of the "Temple" is talking about the mission of antichrist to profane the Holy Name of Jesus, as Jesus spoke about Himself using the term "Temple" before, like when He said in John 2:19: "Destroy this temple, and in three days I will raise it up" which meant His death and resurrection.

Comment: @Bogdan An interesting article relating to this that might help clarify your thoughts is [A Christian view of the coming Temple - opinion](https://www.jpost.com/christianworld/article-705729). Please remember that there are a lot of opinions about all this. Keep your heart open to the Holy Ghost. It's better to receive the fulfillment of prophesy when it happens than to worry about the details early and possibly lead yourself astray.